# How to use appium inspector on a ongoing app execution on SauceLabs

Tags: appium, saucelabs

I've been triying to, on a Saucelabs Private Real device, with either an automatic execution on a live execution, connect my local appium inpector to said execution, so I may inspect the current screen of the app, with no success.

The documentation for eithe SauceLabs or Appium Inspector have not helped.

If someone knows how this could be done i'd be very thankful.